# sumar dos minutos a una fecha con hora

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo una `query` que me traiga los registros que se actualizaron el día de hoy con hora, minutos y segundos iguales ¿Como puedo hacer un `select` para que haya un rango de dos minutos antes y después de la fecha y hora actual ? ya que trabajo con un ciclo `for` y dentro del ciclo coloco un `ajax`, entonces si se envían 10 registros el tiempo ya no coincide y solo me trae 5 ya que pasaron milisegundos y no es la misma hora, mi `query` es, sabiendo que la variable fecha es `DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

```
SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE CAST(F_ENVIO_TEL AS DATETIME2)=CAST('" & fecha & "' AS DATETIME2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder restar o sumar; minutos, segundos, horas en Fechas y Horas puedes hacer uso de: `INTERVAL`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

**Restando Intervalos**

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 4 SECOND;
  >_ 2016-07-01 10:56:16

SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE;
  >_ 2016-07-01 10:54:20

SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
  >_ 2016-07-01 07:56:20

SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
  >_ 2016-06-30 10:56:20
```

**Sumando Intervalos**

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 4 SECOND;
  >_ 2016-07-01 10:56:24

SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE;
  >_ 2016-07-01 10:58:20

SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
  >_ 2016-07-01 13:56:20

SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
  >_ 2016-07-02 10:56:20
```

Posteriormente ya puedes entonces hacer la consulta entre fechas con el uso del `BETWEEN`.

Ejemplo:

```
 SELECT `venta_realizada` FROM `ventas` WHERE `venta_realizada` BETWEEN ('2016-02-23 17:33:57' - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AND ('2016-02-23 17:33:57' + INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
   >_ 2016-02-23 17:44:12
   >_ 2016-02-23 17:33:57
   >_ 2016-02-23 17:36:51
```